# Combine textures with coordinates

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d, textures

Is it possible to add one texture to another texture, at specific coordinates?
Like if I want to add a small texture(16x16) to big texture (1368 x 768) with coordinates ( 100, 100) so the small texture goes to specific coordinates (100, 100 ).

Comment: Other than that it involves textures, coordinates, OpenGL and C++, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I got it. If I split the background texture to 16x16 quads I just need to edit one quad (add other texture to it ) and it is done.

Comment: I still don't get it, but I'm glad you've solved your problem. :D

Comment: So I wanted put other texture to texture ( blend them together) with exact coordinates inside the other texture. Like I wanna put 16x16 texture to 100,100 etc. You got it now ?

Comment: Actually this is a cross post from SO which is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [glTexSubImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml) may be what you are looking for.